# Electric panel, one bad beaker blade?

Tags: electrical

My pool pump went out, it was old, so I checked it. Breaker had tripped. Reset the breaker, flipped on the pump and got a buzz but no function and the breaker tripped. Replaced the pump motor, went to flip the breaker and nothing. Checked with multimeter and no power out of the 240 breaker. Bought a new breaker, same, no power. Did a continuity test on the new and old breakers and both were good. All the other breakers work but that one. The line runs through the garage wall to the pump controller just on the other side of the wall so it’s visible. Checked the line to the controller, it’s fine. No burning or marke near the blade the breaker mates with. Two questions, how could one blade be bad on the bar of blades? How do I test if the blade has power without damaging or shorting the panel. Lost.....maybe a panel reset turning off all the breakers ad flipping the main twice? That’s my next try but confused why the whole bar isn’t out. It’s a dual bar 200 panel.

Comment: What brand breaker panel? When you pull the breaker can you see any damage to the bus bars? 2 brands of panels I know have this problem are federal Pacific. (FPE) stab lock these have a very small contact area and are known for burning the contact and zinsco the 2 bus rails were aluminum and the contacts loosened over time and would start arcing burning away the aluminum bar(s). I have seen this on better quality panels but not very often.

Comment: It’s an I-T-E panel which is a Siemens company. No discoloration anywhere.

Comment: Contact seems nice and firm on the breaker to the bar.

Comment: Is there a way to test the contact blade for power. Not sure if there’s power to the other breakers on the bar why it wouldn’t be hot though. Just getting nothing on the out side of the breaker and they test fine.

Comment: Check the voltage coming into the panel leg to leg should be 240 +/-10% then check ea leg to the neutral each should be 120 +/- 10% if the voltage is good turn the breaker off and pull the breaker and repeat the test on the connecting points and make the same measurements , I have seen some panels that the points are bolted together to make more openings but I have not had a failure on this kind of bus, you should use a face shield or protective eye wear at a minimum and cotton long sleeves and leather or cotton gloves in case you slip, I have to wear flash gear at work any time I work live.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. It was a loose wire on the adjacent breaker.

Comment: Is the ***breaker*** ITE/Murray/Siemens?   Because that make of panel is vulnerable to people attempting to install HOM, BR or other 1" breakers -- these do not properly fit, but seem to "snap in" (an expert would realize the insertion force is wrong).  Also make sure your pool pump is on a GFCI, either a GFCI breaker ($85) or a GFCI device downline. This is important to stop electrical drownings.